# Was this ever valid Elixir syntax?

Tags: elixir

So looking at the source code in this [file](https://github.com/benjamintanweihao/erlang_programming_exercises/blob/master/chapter_4/ring_one.ex), I see a backwards pointing arrow like `pid <- {:message, message, m}`.  Was that ever valid Elixir syntax?  And what is the valid syntax now to make the `RingOne` module behave correctly when I paste it into an iex shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `!` operator was deprecated in favor of `send/2` [in 2014](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/5a2e838def3f5470abff5cbbbc82b22f3e48411e) and [removed a few days later](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/4ade0f98aa820fd8d982417020458dc87f4a4993). It's simple to fix: just change all `a <- b` expressions to `send(a, b)`.